# .NET 8 Standalone Blazor WebAssembly DevServer enable CORS

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

With the .NET 8 changes to Blazor WebAssembly, the "Hosted" option has gone away. Completely reasonable for some circumstances. But the DevServer you get given for debugging it seems to lack near any documentation I can find.

The issue I'm encountering seems to be CORS based and I was curious if there is a command line argument I can provide to the DevServer to ease up on the Policy.

99% of the docs available assume you're using the old style and should just go enable it in the ASP.NET server.
I'd be keen to see if there's a nice way to enable this for the DevServer as I'm confident it's easy enough to deal with for a proper deployment server.

Of course my understanding of this issue could all be horribly wrong. But when the explanation seems to suggest doing something based on the old style. It's an either an oversight in .NET 8 or just something a bit obscure to deal with.

Comment: For .NET 8, you can choose the `Blazor Web App` and choose `Auto` Interactive render mode.

Comment: @Rena Not exactly what I was looking for in regards to my original question. But I have to admit I do rather like this Auto Interactive Render Mode.